# How can I remove p tag if it contains less than 4 characters?

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with removing a paragraph tag whenever it doesn't have content. It gets the content dynamically, but sometimes there's no content for the element, so it get's really ugly. How can I remove the paragraph whenever this happens?

```
// try 1
if ($('.package-codes').length < 4) {
    $(this).remove();
}

// try 2
$('.code').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length < 5 ;
});
```

Here's an codepen of my markup. 
http://codepen.io/michaelwilhelmsen/pen/XbwNaW

EDIT:

After looking at your replies I've realized that the content get's added by ajax, and for some reason the .remove method doesn't get applied to the elements. Could it be because the functions are put in effect before the markup is there?

Comment: Can't you stop it adding the p tag when you're adding the dynamic content if there is no content to be added? Can you add the code where the content is added?

Comment: @Styphon I can't add dynamic content here. It's a plugin with custom markup, and there is no possibility of using php..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to invoke `.remove()` over the filtered elements,

```
$('.code').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().length < 5 ;
}).remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdyBYx)

Comment: Yes, just realized this works in the codepen, but for some reason not at the site as the content gets added by ajax. Maybe some kind of delay on the execution could work?

Comment: Try to run this snippet inside ajax success call back. Most importantly after appending the response.

Answer (score 0):

add remove method after filter, check [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqVbwO)

```
$('.code').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().length < 5 ;
}).remove();
```